# Azure Redis Caching in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redis, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, stackexchange.redis

I am very new to Azure Redis caching. I am using MVC 5 + Entity framework 6.1. and database is Azure SQL Server. Website is also on Azure.

I need to cache few tables in Redis which are used for only read. Current size of these tables are 8 GB and going forward it can increase further.

My questions are:
1) How can I bind these tables in Redis cache?
2) How can I add newly added rows in redis cache? Or do I need to delete and recreate one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at information here : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your tables and store them in the Cache. The following blog explains how you can store your information in SQL Server and Redis Cache. It using MVC and EntityFramework as well.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/05/mvc-movie-app-with-azure-redis-cache-in-15-minutes/

Comment: Already seen this link. Problem is table size is 4 GB and getting 4 GB data in MVC and caching it is big challenge for me. Do you have any other way out?

Comment: If you are trying to store the entire table in Cache, then you should have a startup Job (eg. WebJob) that would populate the Cache which will be a one time operation. After that you should only get the data you need in the WebApp.